# How to kill running queries on connection close

Tags: go, go-gorm

We are using https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/ ORM in our backend and scripts to connect to our PostgreSQL database.

Sometimes while a script is in progress, we kill the job manually by pressing `Ctrl + C` on local or killing the pod / process in production. We do have a `defer DB.Close()` in all scripts and I also added handling SIGINT / SIGTERM signals to do `DB.Close()` on kill.

Issue is even after closing the connection, any existing queries which were already running do not get killed and kept on eating DB resources. Is there a way to kill any queries started by this connection pool before exiting either directly from gorm or through some other hack.

Thought of using `pg_backend_pid()` and killing queries using `pg_stat_activity`, but pid we get while running new `pg_backend_pid()` will not be same as the running ones.

**Version**: `jinzhu/gorm v1.9.2`

Comment: This is what `context.Context` is for. Have you read about that?

Comment: See [this section](https://gorm.io/docs/context.html) of the docs

Comment: Also handle the SO stop signal. As example, as described [here](https://medium.com/@matryer/make-ctrl-c-cancel-the-context-context-bd006a8ad6ff) in this article

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy @Matteo. `db.WithContext` method mentioned on gorm doc is not available it seems. We are currently at v1 jinzhu/gorm v1.9.2. If there is any example which I can look at, that would be really helpful. Will also read up on Context meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [use](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/jinzhu/gorm.v1#DB.BeginTx) `BeginTx(ctx context.Context, opts *sql.TxOptions)` which takes a context as an argument.

And here is a small example for it:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=gorm dbname=gorm password=mypassword sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    ctx := context.Background()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    defer func() {
        signal.Stop(c)
        cancel()
    }()
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-c:
            cancel()
        case <-ctx.Done():
        }
    }()

    transaction, err := db.DB().BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    _, err = transaction.Exec("SELECT pg_sleep(100)")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```